# Is this Dvorak for programmers Vim cheat sheet correct?

Tags: vim, dvorak

I am a long-term user of Dvorak for programmers layout and do not want to change this habit. And I have a serious interest in learning vim, as soon as possible. I have found a cheat sheet which seems very handy for printing it as a set of keyboard stickers compatible with my layout. This is the greatest option because it does not require me to have some saved document or printed picture apart from a laptop with the editor being run in full-screen. Here is the image:

[image: Vi/vim cheat sheet, Dvorak programming version]

But before making the stickers, I want to clarify if the picture is correct. The cheat sheet seems to have some mistakes, for example:

1. There is no #2 note on any key. As far as I understand the wording
   of note #2, this note has to be on the next buttons: <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>. For
   example, `d2w` command means delete 2 words where `w` can
   have some number of repeatings.
2. Some numbers claimed to have some options, I agree with <kbd>0</kbd> as the
   beginning of the line but I do not understand how <kbd>5</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd> became
   loaded with commands.

One thing you might consider useful to understand, digits on keyboard using Dvorak for programmers without a numpad can be typed only with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, sometimes (in heavy GUI applications with lots of hotkeys) this might make some hotkeys with digits unreachable or altered. But maybe this image just has not been reviewed enough times to see the mistake, I am too beginner in Vim to do it myself.

This picture is easy to find on Google, but the layout is far from popular, despite it being really superior in some cases. I wish this cheat sheet to be correct because I believe I am not the only Vim user with this layout. Please report any mistakes that you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a Dvorak user so I can't comment on that aspect of your question. But note #2 applies to every motion/operator/command so I'm not sure how useful or practical it would be to put it on almost every key. FWIW, `d2w` doesn't "delete 2 words": cheat sheets are not substitutes to proper learning.

Other issues with that thing:

- "WORDS" and "words" are not differentiated correctly.
- `$` shouldn't have a dot after it as it doesn't "need a char argument afterwards", same with `%`, `[`, `{`, `}` and plenty of others.
- "Goto match" doesn't accurately describe what `%` does.
- Funnily enough, `F` should have a dot but it doesn't. Same for `T`.
- `A` shouldn't have a dot and it should be red, like `a`.
- Same story for `S`.
- `Q` shouldn't have a dot.
- `B` and `b` are not described correctly.
- `m` should have a dot.

I would recommend you toss that cursed cheat sheet to the bin.